# Plugin to open code/file in Github?

Tags: vim, github

Is anyone aware of a plugin for Vim that will allow me to open the current file on Github (or ideally, even the current selection if in visual mode)?

I had this plugin previously for Sublime Text, and now that I'm using Vim, would like to have the same thing.

**edit**: I am looking for a plugin that will open my web browser to the page on github.com that corresponds to the file I'm currently editing. E.g., If I was editing `foo/bar.js` in my local clone of the `quux` repo in Vim, using this plugin would open `https://github.com/dtb/Quux/blob/master/foo/bar.js`. This is equivalent to [ST2-Githubinator](https://github.com/ehamiter/ST2-GitHubinator).

Comment: GitHub is not a storage facility (well, not in a classical way). So, you want to edit a file in the last commit, if I understand right? What is the name of the plugin for ST2? Since ST2 plugins are written in python, and Vim supports python scripting that would help very much as a starting point.

Comment: Why do you want to open the file on GitHub? Do you want to edit "gists"? Is it [this plugin](https://github.com/bgreenlee/sublime-github) or [this one](https://github.com/ehamiter/ST2-GitHubinator)? Please be more specific.

Comment: Oh dear, I didn't describe this well. I want a plugin that will open my web browser to the page on github.com that corresponds to the file I'm currently editing. @romainl, this is the latter plugin (ST2-Githubinator.)

Comment: OK, you should accept Conner's answer, then. But my question remains: what is the point of opening this page on Github? What information or tools or whatever makes it useful?

Comment: If I want to point a block of code out to someone, I can highlight it in Vim, then use the plugin to get a link to the code and send it to them. Very handy, especially when they're not in the same room. Github's file browser is quite nice, so it's not a bad place to read code. Make sense?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [fugitive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/) plugin has `:help fugitive-:Gbrowse` that will do what you want. It's also awesome in general.

```
                                            *fugitive-:Gbrowse*
:[range]Gbrowse         If the remote for the current branch is on GitHub,
                        open the current file, blob, tree, commit, or tag
                        (with git-web--browse) on GitHub.  Otherwise, open the
                        current file, blob, tree, commit, or tag in
                        git-instaweb (if you have issues, verify you can run
                        "git instaweb" from a terminal).  If a range is given,
                        it is appropriately appended to the URL as an anchor.
                        To use with GitHub FI, point g:fugitive_github_domains
                        at a list of domains:

                        let g:fugitive_github_domains = ['git.example.com']

:[range]Gbrowse!        Like :Gbrowse, but put the URL on the clipboard rather
                        than opening it.
```

Comment: Excellent! For some reason I thought I had looked at Fugitive and it didn't do this.

Answer (score 1):

One addition: if your remote is not on github or you are using mercurial my [aurum](https://bitbucket.org/ZyX_I/aurum) has similar functionality (it won’t ever run `git instaweb` though): [`:AuHyperlink`](http://vimpluginloader.sourceforge.net/doc/aurum.txt.html#line196-0). List of supported git remotes can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/ZyX_I/aurum/src/tip/autoload/aurum/drivers/common/hypsites.vim) (search for `s:hyp.git`, link points to the latest revision). In addition to copying link to the HTML formatted file, `:AuHyperlink` can also copy URLs with annotated version of the file, URL of the current or given revision, URL of the page with file history or repository log, push and clone URLs. It is not so well tested with git though: I use almost only mercurial (version with python support) and there are no other users participating in development.

In order not to copy URL to system clipboard, but to open browser you will have to use something like

```
AuHyperlink cmd call\ system('xdg-open\ '.shellescape(%s))
```

(replace `xdg-open` with your favorite browser if it does not work as-is).