# Is there an Xcode plugin for opening a file on Github?

Tags: xcode, plugins, github

I'm looking for a plugin which allows to open a file on Github (in a browser) directly from xcode. It might be useful, for example, when you want to find the commit where some line of code was added and post a comment to it on Github.

AppCode is already has this feature. It's called "Open in browser" and you can find it in the context menu.

I've also found that it is [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352034/plugin-to-open-code-file-in-github/11353201#11353201) in Vim with fugitive plugin.

Does somebody know a ready-to-use plugin for it or should I think about writing own?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with https://github.com/wojteklu/xcode-open-on-github.

It can also open a specific line number in github.

Comment: I think this won't work any more right?

Comment: Since Xcode Plugins have been deprecated, this would work: https://github.com/wojteklu/xcode-open-on-github

Comment: Thanks, that's a good alternative. I updated the answer.